# Installing Open Source Ticket Manager Brimir

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to ruby on rails.... I want to install OPEN SOURCE TICKET MANAGER created by BRIMIR **http://getbrimir.com/** .... I have installed ruby 1.9.3, bundler 1.0.10.... but when i tried to install gem by giving command **bundle install** it shows following fatal error

```
NOTE: Gem.source_index is deprecated, use Specification. It will be removed on o
r after 2011-11-01.
Gem.source_index called from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/
lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:3.
Fetching https://github.com/ivaldi/foundation_rails_helper.git
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/source.rb:560:in
``': No such file or directory - git clone "https://github.com/ivaldi/foundation
_rails_helper.git" "C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/cache/bundler/git/foundation_
rails_helper-c76b733ae8c7a4126f399e570cfc6ba3596f5359" --bare --no-hardlinks (Er
rno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/sour
ce.rb:560:in `git'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/sour
ce.rb:619:in `cache'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/sour
ce.rb:532:in `specs'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/defi
nition.rb:147:in `block in resolve'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/defi
nition.rb:145:in `each'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/defi
nition.rb:145:in `resolve'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/defi
nition.rb:90:in `specs'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/defi
nition.rb:85:in `resolve_remotely!'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/inst
aller.rb:35:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/inst
aller.rb:8:in `install'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/cli.
rb:226:in `install'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vend
or/thor/task.rb:22:in `run'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vend
or/thor/invocation.rb:118:in `invoke_task'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vend
or/thor.rb:246:in `dispatch'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/lib/bundler/vend
or/thor/base.rb:389:in `start'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.10/bin/bundle:13:in
 `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
        from C:/Ruby193/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Don't try to run production Rails apps on Windows. You're gonna have a bad time.

Answer (score 1):

Most gems do not like to work in Windows. You should use a better operating system (just any OS different than Windows should work)

Answer (score 0):

after seeing you error stack trace i guess either u have't installed git on your computer or u have not set its Path. please double check it. after that when i copy and paste this link "https://github.com/ivaldi/foundation_rails_helper.git" then i found 404 error. which mean the url its trying to clone the project is not valid anymore. you should look this link "https://github.com/ivaldi/brimir" and follow the instructions.